# Custom validator not call @service_container

Tags: php, symfony, service, customvalidator

Symfony version: 2.5

**Error**

> "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Intermedius\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\RegisteredEmailValidator::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given, called in D:\Projektek\pricing_tool\backend\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 71 and defined in D:\Projektek\pricing_tool\backend\src\Intermedius\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\RegisteredEmailValidator.php line 22"

**RegisteredEmail.php**

```
 class RegisteredEmail extends Constraint
 {
    public $message = "MSG";
 }
```

**RegistereEmailValidator.php**

```
class RegisteredEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator{
    public $containerInterface;

     function __construct(ContainerInterface $containerInterface)
     {
          $this->containerInterface = $containerInterface;
     }


     public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
     {

        if (!$constraint instanceof RegisteredEmail) {
           throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__ . '\RegisteredEmail');
     }

   }



   public function validateBy()
   {
       return "registered_email";
   }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
  intermedius.user.validator.registered_email:
    class: Intermedius\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\RegisteredEmail
    arguments: [ @service_container ]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: registered_email }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class of your validator service definition should be set to the validator class, not the constraint.

```
class: Intermedius\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\RegisteredEmailValidator
```

Comment: What is the namespace of your RegisteredEmailValidator class? and why do you need to strongly tight your validator to the container?

Answer (score 0):

You should not inject the `service_container` in your services. In your example you should rather inject only the services you need instead. See for example the "Avoiding your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container" section of http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html.